# AngularJS Two way data binding between controller and service

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I have a service in angular JS which is defined as follows:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Offering.AccountService', [])

.service('Account', function($http, config) {

    var account = this;

    account.accountDetails = {};

    this.getAccountDetails = function(){
        var request = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: config.accountURL,
            headers: {
                'X-Parse-Application-Id': config.applicationID,
                'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': config.restAPIKey,
            }
        })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('Successfully aqquired account details');
            account.accountDetails = data.results[0];

        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.warn(status);
        });
    }


});
```

This service calls out to an endpoint to retrieve some data, I am calling this method in the run function of the main module as is shown below:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Offering', [
    'routerRoutes'
])

.run(function(Account){
    Account.getAccountDetails();
})
```

In my controller, I have a variable called balance, in which I want to store the value retrieved from the service, as is shown in the code below:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Offering.HomeController', [])

.controller('HomeCtrl', function(Account) {

    this.data = {
        message: "Account Details",
        updateBalance: function() {
            Account.getAccountDetails()
        },
        balance: Account.accountDetails.balance
    }

    // this.$watch(
    //     function () { return Account.accountDetails; },
    //     function (data) {
    //         $scope.data.balance = data.balance
    //     },
    //     true
    // );
})
```

The data from the service is returned after the controller data object has been set up and thus the balance field is not getting populated. If I use the $scope.watch approach that is commented out, then the data object gets populated properly. However, I was under the assumption that this need not be done as there is a two way data binding between the service and the controller. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: This is typically handled by returning a promise from your service and setting the data in your controller when the promise is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.run` function doesn't stop to wait for the `getAccountDetails` to return a value. And so, when you assign `this.data.balance = Account.accountDetails.balance`, you are essentially doing this: `this.data.balance = undefined`.

As per comment above, the typical way is to have `getAccountDetails()` to return a promise, like so:

```
this.getAccountDetails = function(){
   return $http({...})
       .then(function(response){
          console.log("successfully returned balanace", response.data);
          return response.data;
       });
}
```

Then, in the controller:

```
var vm = this;
Account.getAccountDetails()
  .then(function(accountDetails){
     vm.balance = accountDetails.balance;
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did not want to do this in the controller as I would like to use the data returned in multiple controllers. Is there any way I can do this before any of the controllers are set up so that I do not have to do it in every controller?

Comment: If you populate, rather than overwrite, the initially-empty `accountDetails` object, then you could `$watch` it for changes. However, that is not efficient, as it will be done on every digest. The other way would be to use the `resolve` property of `$routeProvider` or the more powerful `$stateProvider` - this allows you to resolve all the async dependencies prior to navigating to the View, and inject them into all the dependent controllers.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can not put a watch on the function which is returning promise, better you could put watch on `this.data`, Their is different way of put watch while using this keyword inside controller.

**CODE**

```
$scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function () {
    return this.data; 
  }), function (newVal, oldVal) {
    // now we will pickup changes to newVal and oldVal
  });
```

Hope this could help you , Thanks.